# Order for Muslim of non-Islamic state... if he has joined the army of that nation

Tags: islamic-scholar, jihad

if a Muslim brother belongs to non Islamic nation ....&  he has joined armed forces of that non islamic nation.....what did islam preach for him if he is fighting against  Muslim nation...  1) to be sincere with his own country because he took an oath for the protection of his mother land & Islam criticize very much for the implementation of oath....2) to be sincere with Muslims ..break his oath.. took resign from that armed forces so that he would not be responsible of Muslims  blood shed .. i was basically confused in the matter of oath already took by a Muslim brother from a side of non Islamic state & Is jihad from that side is eligible because that non Islamic country also contains the majority percentage of Muslim's as compare to the Muslim state..which of them is superior...plz give the answer in a light quran or hadis.....Jihad is purely for Allah Almighty  for the protection of Islam . Islam was also their in that side of the border .so in that matter i was little bit confused to be volunteer from that side of Muslim percentage is a sin or not

Comment: in my question i was basically confused in the matter of oath already took by a Muslim brother from a side of non Islamic state & jihad from that side is eligible because that country also contains the majority percentage of Muslim's as compare to the Muslim state so that question cannot gives the proper satisfactory answer of my question

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Jihad' against a Muslim state. Jihad is war for the cause of Allah, not just any war in which Muslims participate.

Comment: yes sir i know Jihad is purely for Allah Almighty but for the protection of Muslims properties and families as i have mentioned now in  the question that this country also contains a majority Muslims percentage as compare to the Muslim state so in that matter i was little bit confused to be volunteer from that side of Muslim percentage is a sin or not

Comment: Defensive Jihad is for protection of Darul Islam, not for protection of Darul Harab in which Muslims might live.

Comment: but Islam was also their on that side with much more percentage....

Comment: You explicitly say "non islamic nation", which implies to me that they are not fighting for Islam, are not ruled by Muslims and not ruled in accordance to Islamic law. In that case numbers do not matter, it is Darul Harab when in war with an Islamic state. How can a non-Muslim war be Jihad?

Comment: i got my answer sir thanks for your precious time ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving another ansewer, as you have edited your question to say that there are a greater proportion of Muslims in this non-Muslim country compared to the Muslim country, in this situation you describe. But I am keeping the other ansewer as it describes a situation that would mostly likely occur. Like my previous ansewer, there cannot be any (absolutely none) non-Muslims in this army, only Muslims. And I will quote the verse again so you do not have to refer to different answers:

Or think ye that ye shall be abandoned, as though God did not know those among you who strive with might and main, and take none for friends and protectors except God, His Apostle, and the (community of) Believers? But God is well- acquainted with (all) that ye do. (9:16)

Okay say the army is completely Muslims and you ar reling only on Allah and Muslims for help in the fight even though your country is non-Muslim. Now there is a situation described in the Quran where the hands of the Muslims were restrained by Allah from attacking the non-Muslims on account of there being some Muslims being present amongst the non-Muslims. Allah restrained there hands so the Muslims would not fight their fellow brothers:

And He it is Who hath withheld men's hands from you, and hath withheld your hands from them, in the valley of Mecca, after He had made you victors over them. Allah is Seer of what ye do. (48:24) These it was who disbelieved and debarred you from the Inviolable Place of Worship, and debarred the offering from reaching its goal. And if it had not been for believing men and believing women, whom ye know not - lest ye should tread them under foot and thus incur guilt for them unknowingly; that Allah might bring into His mercy whom He will - If (the believers and the disbelievers) had been clearly separated We verily had punished those of them who disbelieved with painful punishment. (48:25) When those who disbelieve had set up in their hearts zealotry, the zealotry of the Age of Ignorance, then Allah sent down His peace of reassurance upon His messenger and upon the believers and imposed on them the word of self-restraint, for they were worthy of it and meet for it. And Allah is Aware of all things. (48:26)

So in this situation the Messenger (pbuh) was given the command of self-restraint.

I must add that, how a non-Muslim country has a greater proportion of Muslims than a Muslim country is confusing since Muslims cannot migrate to a non-Muslim country, except for a brief business trip or Jihad or Dawah. The majority of Muslims do not come to non-Muslim countries for these reasons. This is part of the problem, it is better if the Muslims go to the own countries. As for the hypothetical person you are talking about, he clearly is not in the non-muslim country for a brief business trip, or Jihad (he is fighting but this is not Jihad as it is not for islam) or Dawah, so he should go back to his Muslim country of origin or any Muslim country.

Comment: What about pak-india...India has a greatest proportion of Muslim population than Pakistan. but India is a non islamic state

Comment: You should read about why India was split into india-pak, and what was the reasons behind these Muslims tfor saying behind

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation the army the Muslim will probably be in will have a mix of non-Muslims with Muslims. And the non-Muslims will probably be more than the Muslims. Even if a Muslim country becomes an enemy to your country, you cannot get help from non-Muslims to aid you with the fight. You cannot fight along side non-Muslims thinking that their number will help you. In any fight you must only make allies with the Muslims or Allah only, this is in the Quran:

Or think ye that ye shall be abandoned, as though God did not know those among you who strive with might and main, and take none for friends and protectors except God, His Apostle, and the (community of) Believers? But God is well- acquainted with (all) that ye do. (9:16)

This is also evident in the opposite situation of what you describe i.e. when non-Muslims are in a Muslim country, and another country attacks this Muslim country, the non-Muslims are not permitted to fight. This is because Muslims must only get help from Allah and other Muslims in a fight.

This possibly hypothetical person you are talking about should not have joined a non-Muslim army, to start off with. If he has made an oath, possibly because he did not know, I would advise him to break it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obedience in disobedience to Allah  <sup>[1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/95/12),[2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/77)</sup> . Similar to how you can not make a promise to worship an idol, you can not make a promise to fight with disbelievers against the Muslims and hence destroy the lives and properties of Muslims.

> لا يتخذ المؤمنون الكافرين أولياء من دون المؤمنين ومن يفعل ذلك فليس من الله في شيء إلا أن تتقوا منهم تقاة ويحذركم الله نفسه وإلى الله المصير
>
> Let not believers take disbelievers as allies rather than believers. And whoever [of you] does that has nothing with Allah, except when taking precaution against them in prudence. And Allah warns you of Himself, and to Allah is the [final] destination.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:28](http://quran.com/3/28)</sup>

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا لا تتخذوا اليهود والنصارى أولياء بعضهم أولياء بعض ومن يتولهم منكم فإنه منهم إن الله لا يهدي القوم الظالمين
>
> O you who have believed, do not take the Jews and the Christians as allies. They are [in fact] allies of one another. And whoever is an ally to them among you - then indeed, he is [one] of them. Indeed, Allah guides not the wrongdoing people.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:51](http://quran.com/5/51)</sup>